# Nvidia X Server Settings cannot edit display configuration (screen tearing)

Tags: nvidia, screen, tearing

I'm experiencing some screen tearing on my ThinkPad x1 extreme gen 2, running Ubuntu 20.04. The Nvidia X Server Settings app was already installed and on first sight the driver is in use.

I'm however still experiencing screen tearing. After some googling I quickly came to inspect the X Server Display Configuration panel, but I cannot edit it. See screenshot below.

I'm new to linux, any help is greatly appreciated. I don't quite know where to begin :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After more digging I assumed the problem was that Nvidia Optimus sync wasn't enabled (didn't know what this meant, but I assume it means that you have a laptop with both nvidia and intel card). A lot of posts suggested to edit/create a file called `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm-nomodeset.conf` but that did not work for me.

What **did work** was to create a file called:

`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/zz-nvidia-modeset.conf`

Add the following line:

`options nvidia_drm modeset=1`

Then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot. After that, running `sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset` finally returned `Y` for me. At last the screen stopped tearing.